# What does this awk function exactly do?

Tags: awk

I made a post a while ago in which i was seeking help for fixing a text file..
My problem was that I had a text file, which the lines where placed incorrectly..

example:

https://pastebin.com/mLfzxcxB

in which the purpose of the script was to concatenate the probabilities of each sentence in the correct order..

So in this case would the end result be

https://pastebin.com/6vApi6cs

One of the many solution was this:

```
awk 'NF == 2{ match($1,/^[0-9]+(_[0-9]+){7}/); k = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH); next }
     { $NF=""; a[k]=a[k]"\n "$0 }
     END { for(i in a) printf "%s [%s ]\n\n",i,a[i] }' input
```

I am currently struggling to understand why it actually works?.. 
how does it concatenate the correct the probabilities accurately?..

Sorry for making a "repost", but I could not find the original post, which is why I have to do it like this.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the information. I changed the example, with one I've been using it on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '
NF == 2 {                            # for those records with 2 fields
    match($1,/^[0-9]+(_[0-9]+){7}/)  # look for 1_1_1_1_0_0_1_0_2279
    k = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)    # k=1_1_1_1_0_0_1_0_2279
    next                             # skip to next record
}
{                                    # for all the other kinds of records
    $NF=""                           # delete the ] from the end
    a[k]=a[k]"\n "$0                 # hash into a using k as key, "grouping"
}
END {                                # after all data is grouped into a
    for(i in a)                      # for each key
        printf "%s [%s ]\n\n",i,a[i] # print the key and the data
}' input
```

*What does this awk function exactly do?* Basically, it turns these:

```
1_1_1_1_1_0_1_0_666  [
  1 0 0 ]
1_1_1_1_1_0_1_0_666  [
  0 1 0 ]
```

into this:

```
1_1_1_1_1_0_1_0_666  [
  1 0 0
  0 1 0 ]
```

It does *concatenate the probabilities of each sentence in the* order they appear in the input file and prints the "sentences" out in random order.